# How can I do something if a widget enters the internal environment of another widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I run a function if a widget covers another widget (it doesn't necessarily need to cover the entire underlying widget, if only a little of it was covered)

This is the code for draggable widgets:

```
import tkinter as tk
from drag import Draggable


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

a = tk.Label(root, bg="black", width=15, height=1, text="Main menu", fg="white", font=("Roboto", 12))
a.pack()

b = tk.Label(root, bg="black", width=15, height=1, text="Start", fg="white", font=("Roboto", 12))
b.pack()

c = tk.Button(root, text="Hello", bg="blue")
c.pack()

Draggable(a)
Draggable(b)
Draggable(c)

root.mainloop()
```

And this is the Draggable module code:

```
class Draggable:
    def __init__(self, widget):
            self.widget = widget
            
            self.widget.bind("<Button-1>", self.__StartDrag)
            self.widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.__MotionDrag)
            
    def __StartDrag(self, event):
            self.widget.startX = event.x
            self.widget.startY = event.y
    
    def __MotionDrag(self, event):
            x = self.widget.winfo_x() - self.widget.startX + event.x
            y = self.widget.winfo_y() - self.widget.startY + event.y
            
            self.widget.place(x=x, y=y)
```

Comment: It's too broad. Implement a prototype by checking if bounding rectangles overlap, and ask a specific question if you confront a problem